# How to implement an effecient matrix data structure in java?

Tags: java

Is there a builtin data structure in java that lets me do this:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); // No fixed size, and O(1) to initate

matrix.set(x,y,32); // adds 32 to arbitrary positions x and y in O(1)
matrix.isempty(x,y); // returns true or false wether x,y has been set to a value
matrix.clear(); // clears all elements in O(1)
```

You cannot use a two dimensional array, because you need to initate it to a fixed size, which takes O(x*y). You cannot use a list of lists, because you cannot add objects to arbitrary positions.

Comment: I would use a HashMap, or TObjectIntHashMap unless you have a more specific requirement.  BTW There is libraries like Colt which support sparse arrays/matricies.

Comment: The second-person imperative implies this is *homework*.  Some people mind this. I however do not =D

Comment: I see nowhere where you set the size.  Is there any concept of "reading off the end"?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Google Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) collection class [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html). Might be an option unless this class is too heavyweight for you.

Comment: OP says they're looking for "a builtin data structure" or else I would have recommended the same thing.

Comment: @DanO : Maybe built-in means "I don't want to implement it myself". I think this is a quite good answer.

Comment: Indeed. I missed that. Hopefully, it helps anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering just these operations, you could implement it thanks to a `HashMap<java.awt.Point,SomeType>`, but I don't think it already exists this way.

Comment: @ScottHunter : Nothing in the doc enables me to be positive about that but knowing the general implementation details of `HashMap`, I think that `clear` only consists in allocating a new array and updating some fields.

Comment: I could be wrong, I just saw an implementation of HashMap that keeps the same capacity after `clear`, so it has to set all the values of the table to `null`, which is a O(n).